# Is setting input tag's checked attribute preferable to simply marking as checked?

Tags: html

I have seen folks mark an HTML checkbox as checked by writing the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked/>
```

Is it preferable to instead write the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
```

If so, why?

Comment: Browsers are supposed to serialise the attribute (e.g. when using innerHTML) using `checked="checked"` so you might find it appearing in code that has been written in a design mode frame or content editable region and then exported.

Comment: @Neil — Which spec says that?

Comment: @Quentin Sorry, I must have imagined it. I even tried to research the effect of setting the defaultChecked property in case that was what I had misremembered but I couldn't find a spec for that either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are synonymous. There is no difference at all between them.

Personally I think just `checked` is better because the extra 10 characters in `="checked"` are completely redundant and a waste of space.

Comment: They are only synonymous if you aren't writing XHTML.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing XHTML, the correct way to do it would be `checked="checked"` because XHTML requires complete attributes.